# If array size is more than 0 then only push data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, toggle

I am toggling my `div` on `ng-click` using `isVisible`. The problem I am having is that everytime I click the button, it runs `$scope.Objectlist.push(data);`. I want to only push it on the first click or push only if array size is less than or equal to 0.

```
$scope.objectlist = [];
$scope.isVisible = false;
$scope.pushData= function(id) {
    $http.get("some variables being passed on here").success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            $scope.objectlist.push(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        alert("Error");
    });
    $scope.isVisible = ! $scope.isVisible;
};
```

I have tried using `if(Objectlist.length <= 0)` but it returned null for my array meaning nothing got pushed.

Comment: Do you mean `if ($scope.Objectlist ...)` ?

Comment: before `$http.get` insert: `if($scope.objectlist.length != 0) { return; }`

Comment: @user4756836 actually not. You still can do double-push if click very fast. try insert this before `$http.get` this code: `if($scope.isVisible) {return;}`; so `pushData` will make http request only once; but it still is not totally  correct :D

Comment: @befzz what would be the most correct solution here?

Comment: @user4756836 that will work as u want. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want to use counter or boolean variable for this. Imagine you set counter to 1 or boolean variable to "true" and some other function you'll add later removes all elements from array. Then you have empty array which requires pushing, but counter says it's not 0 and boolean variable says something is already pushed to array. This is obviously wrong so I think you should check array length directly like this.

```
$scope.Objectlist = [];
$scope.isVisible = false;
$scope.pushData= function(id) {
    $http.get("some variables being passed on here").success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if ($scope.Objectlist.length === 0) {  
            $scope.Objectlist.push(data); /* Push only if array is empty */
        }
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        alert("Error");
    });
    $scope.isVisible = ! $scope.isVisible;
};
```

Comment: This will not work if I am getting multiple different objects with different object sizes. Some are empty while some are nto

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple. Try this.

```
$scope.Objectlist = [];
$scope.isVisible = false;
$scope.clicks = 0;                     // Count the number of clicks
$scope.pushData= function(id) {
    $http.get("some variables being passed on here").success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        $scope.clicks += 1;
        if ($scope.clicks === 1 || $scope.Objectlist.length === 0) {  
            $scope.Objectlist.push(data);
        }
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        alert("Error");
    });
    $scope.isVisible = ! $scope.isVisible;
};
```

Create a variable `clicks` that stores the number of clicks. Create a condition that checks if the number of clicks equals 1 and the length of the array is 0.